# How to get Visual Studio 2017 to not use a dynamic port with local IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017

I have a website defined locally in IIS and I can navigate to it with my browser without issue. When I try to debug the project in Visual Studio 2017 I receive a timeout error trying to connect to 127.1.1.1:38545

In the project I have the server set to Local IIS (not Express) and a project URL specified http://mylocalproject.mydomain.com (same as what I have the domain defined in IIS and my Windows hosts file)

Any idea what I need to do to get Visual Studio to use the specified URL instead of trying to use a dynamic port?

Comment: Can you run Visual Studio Project Diagnostics to reveal the relevant settings? https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: Seems that you need to be using Jexus to have that option in Visual Studio.